# Infinite alternating series problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

While studying Leibniz test for infinite alternating series I am having an intuition, consider a series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}u_{n} $$
If
$$ \left \{ u_{n} \right \} $$
is a non-decreasing sequence of non-negative real numbers, such that
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} u_{n} = 0 $$
Then, the series does not converge.

Can we prove this? or can anyone please provide a counter example to it?

Comment: Do you know a lot of non-decreasing non-negative sequences that tend to $0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $u_n$ is non-decreasing, non-negative and $
\lim u_n=0$ then $u_n=0$ for all $n$ so the series converges.

If 'non-decreasing' is changed to 'non-increasing' then convergence follows by Leibniz test.